# Passing complex javascript object to controller. List of objects are always 0

Tags: javascript, c#, angular

I have a object that I am trying to pass to my C# controller. All the properties get populated except the list I have is always count =0. I have tried setting the header to content-type/json and Json.stringify. Also for testing I am returning the product list from another call so I know that returns a list of products to my view that is formatted correctly.

example for creating request

```
 var request =
'Id':null, 
...
... rest of data is here standard properites
 ...
'Products':productlist
```

for product list I am currently using the return value from a call that returns a List

```
        return $http.post('api/Enty/Save', request )
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
               errorLog('error: ' + data);
           });



public class Person:IPerson
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(90)]
    public String Address1 { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(90)]
    public String Address2 { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(40)]
    public String Address3 { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(40)]
    public String City { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(2)]
    public String State { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(40)]
    public String Province { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(10)]
    public String Zip { get; set; }

 public IList<IProduct> Products { get; set; }


}


    [HttpPost()]

    public Response Save(person r)
    {}
```

**UPDATE**

If I make it List instead of IList it works. Any ideas why?

Comment: the request object is created like this

'Id':null,
'Products':productlist

for product list I am currently using the return value from a call that returns a List<products>

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was not the Ilist but the Iproduct. I just changed to a concrete class for that property